# How to format a byte string to set a value with cbt set (cloud bigtable command line tool)?

Tags: command-line, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have a field in Bigtable storing a timestamp. Using `cbt lookup`, the field displays like this `"\x00\x00\x01d\x865W\x00"`

This bytestring converts to an integer, for example via Python.

```
int.from_bytes(b"\x00\x00\x01d\x865W\x00",'big')
1531260000000
```

`1531260000000` is a unix timestamp in microseconds. [Converting](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) to a human-readable format gives `2018-07-10T22:00:00+00:00`

How can we update this field to a different timestamp using **cbt**?

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#set_value_of_a_cell) we get the command

`cbt set <table> <row> family:column=val`

But how should the value be formatted to store it correctly?

I've tried `cbt set mytable row1 family:timestamp=1531260000000`, but then `cbt lookup` displays it as `1531260000000`, not as a bytestring, and BigQuery does not display it at all, failing because the format is wrong.

I've also tried tried `cbt set mytable row1 family:timestamp="\x00\x00\x01d\x865W\x00"`, but then `cbt lookup` displays the bytestring with escaped backslashes, which also does not work: `"\\x00\\x00\\x01d\\x865W\\x00"`

I looked in the [source code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigtable/cmd/cbt/cbt.go#L1153) for cbt but I'm not familiar enough with Go to figure it out from there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why store a timestamp as a cell value at all? Bigtable already maintains a timestamp field for every cell, and if you want you can override it to be something other than the current time: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#storage-model

Comment: @DouglasMcErlean because it is a 1-1 copy of fields from another database, and that's how it was stored there, also due to the translation/copying tools working that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1195), you are not able to pass arbitrary bytes with cbt. The timestamp you provided is handled like a string by cbt, that's why it is escaped.

Answer (score 2):

From the current documentation looks like this could be done using a $’\’
I added an example from the documentation for lookup:

cbt -project my-project -instance my-instance lookup my-table $'\224\257\312W\365:\205d\333\2471\315\'

Please refer to the cbt reference for more information:
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference